# set orders partiallity

Tags: functions

$( A,\le)$ and $(A',\le')$ are partially ordered sets. A map $\phi : A \to A'$ is called *order preserving*  from $(A, \le)$ to $(A', \le')$ if for all  $x, y \in A : x \le y \implies \phi(x) \le'   \phi(y)$

For example:

For $(P(\{1,2\}), \subseteq)$ and $(\mathbb{N}, \le)$ is the map
$\phi : P(\{1,2\}) \to \mathbb{N} : X \mapsto \sum_{n \in X} n\:$ *order preserving*  from $(P(\{1,2\},\subseteq)$ to  $(\mathbb{N}, \le)$ - and also injective.

Is there injective, *order preserving* map from $(\mathbb{N}, | )$ to $(\mathbb{N},\le)$ ?

I would say no because if there is an injective *order preserving* map $\phi : \N \rightarrow \N$ then $\phi$ would be unrestricted, which is a contradiction to injective property...

Is ir correct?

THX people

Comment: Does $\mathbb{N}$ contain $0$ or not?

Comment: Yes...the 0 is also inlcuded

Comment: ok, I actually answered for both possibilities below

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since it's unclear from the problem statement whether $\mathbb{N} = \{0, 1, \ldots\}$ or $\mathbb{N} = \{1, 2, \ldots\}$ in this context, I'll answer for both possibilities.  Let's call $\mathbb{N}_0 = \{0, 1, \ldots\}$ and $\mathbb{N}_1 = \{1,2,\ldots\}$ to disambiguate.   I'm also assuming that $|$ means "divides" here.

There is an injective, order-preserving map $f$ from $(\mathbb{N}_1, |)$ to $(\mathbb{N}_1, \leq)$.  In fact the identity function $f(n) = n$ will work:  if $m|n$, then $m\leq n$.

There is *no* injective, order-preserving map from $(\mathbb{N}_0, |)$ to $(\mathbb{N}_0, \leq)$.  The partial order $(\mathbb{N}_0, |)$ has a largest element, $0$, so if $f$ were some such map, then $0\leq f(n) < f(0)$ for every $n \neq 0$.  There are infinitely many numbers $n\neq 0$ but only finitely many numbers $m$ with $0\leq m < f(0)$, so such a map cannot be injective.

In either case, there is an injective, order-preserving map in the other direction (that is, from $(\mathbb{N}, \leq)$ to $(\mathbb{N}, |)$).  One may take $f(n) = 2^n$, for instance; $m\leq n$ implies that $2^m|2^n$.

Comment: thx a lot for your help...

Comment: @user113922: If the answer was useful to you, you should [accept](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work) it.